# ASP.NET Core and Postman. Error in creating an object (POST)

Tags: json, asp.net-core, postman

I have applications with a simple [HttpPost] method in controller that should accept an object from the query body (query from postman).
However, I have an error every time because null comes to the method - not object.

Model:

```
public class MeetupDto
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Organizer { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public bool IsPrivate { get; set; }
    }
```

Method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Post([FromBody]MeetupDto model) 
{
     ...
}
```

The method works fine when I shrink the model down to the name and organizer only. When there's a date or a bool, it doesn't work.

Postman (body raw+json):
https://localhost:44398/api/meetup/

```
"name": "JsEvent",
"organizer": "chrome",
"date": "2020-07-26 15:20:00",
"isPrivate": "false"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. You're sending a `string` for `IsPrivate`, when it's expecting a `bool`
2. You're not using the correct [date format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Change your JSON to this:

```
// Note the 'T' in the date
{
    "name": "JsEvent",
    "organizer": "chrome",
    "date": "2020-07-26T15:20:00",
    "isPrivate": false
}
```

and it should bind your model correctly.